# How do I selectively round UITableViewCell corners?

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to recreate the feel of the upper part of the iPhone Stocks application. Using cornerRadius I have been able to round all the corners of the UITableView, but when the user drags too far down or up the rectangular edges of the first and last cells show. How can I round only the top or bottom part of the UITableViewCell?